# How to align text next to image inside of a details element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my text next to my image inside of the details tag in HTML, but when I try, it keeps putting it under the image instead of above.

The preferable end result is the image aligned on the right side of the image beside it.

N.B. i am trying to avoid the use of float to do the desired answer

relevant HTML/PHP code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=MuseoModerno:wght@900&family=Overlock:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baskervville&family=MuseoModerno:wght@900&family=Overlock:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap');

    h1 {
      font-family: 'MuseoModerno', cursive;
      margin-left: 1em;
    }

    h2 {
      font-family: 'MuseoModerno', cursive;
    }

    p {
      font-family: 'Baskervville', serif;
    }

    span {
      font-family: 'Baskervville', serif;
    }

    .art1 {
      border: 5px solid black;
      margin: 2em;
      padding: 1em;
      box-shadow: 9px 10px 14px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 10px 14px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
      -moz-box-shadow: 9px 10px 14px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
    }

    img {
      width: 20em;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    span {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .wrap-around {
      padding-left: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<details class="art1" style="background-color: #FFA500;">
          <summary>Gluttony</summary>
          <h2>Gluttony</h2>
          <p>Written by: 1</p>
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5CFI.jpg" alt="Painting of gluttony.jpg personified">
          <p class="wrap-around">is an inordinate desire to consume more that which one requires. The punishment in hell is that you'll be force-fed rats, toads, and snakes. It is linked with the pig and the color orange.</p><br>
          <span>This article was last edited: Thursday, 27. January 2022.</span>
        </details>
```

Comment: Please post the complide code maybe using code snippet so we can see the issue

Comment: @DarkBee Posted an example of how the code looks generated. the image is unaccasable without accessing to the turing server connected.

Comment: accident @DarkBee

Comment: No problem, I've added a placeholder image so an image is shown in the example

Comment: @DarkBee Should be good now, thanks for the edits

Comment: _"but when I try"_ - where _did_ you try? I don't see anything in your CSS, that would accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: @CBroe because I removed them as they did not work.

Comment: @CBroe I can readd them

Comment: @CBroe the code is edited, and i have added a specification where I am trying to avoid using float to do it

Comment: The text already goes next to the image, if the whole page is wide enough. And stating _that_ you want to avoid float, without giving a reason _why_, is not really helpful.

Comment: @CBroe Got told that using float can give an unexpected result with other elements involved. And I got told its pretty outdated to use float to achieve the same result.

Comment: _"And I got told its pretty outdated to use float to achieve the same result."_ - but you weren't told any alternatives, at the same time? And you did not ask that person, right then and there ...? A current technique to achieve this would be `flexbox`.

Comment: @CBroe did ask the person, the person did not respond. I've tried using flexbox to align the image, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'll try again then.

Comment: flexbox needs to be applied to the container element. Using the `details` element for that here is probably not a good idea, because then _everything_ inside will become flex items. So first of all adding a container element that groups the image and the text that should show next to it, would be advisable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a div for image and text and made it display flex. Hope this is what you're looking for.

```
<details class="art1" style="background-color: #FFA500;">
          <summary>Gluttony</summary>
          <h2>Gluttony</h2>
          <p>Written by: 1</p>
          <div class="image-text">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5CFI.jpg" alt="Painting of gluttony.jpg personified">
          <p class="wrap-around">is an inordinate desire to consume more that which one requires. The punishment in hell is that you'll be force-fed rats, toads, and snakes. It is linked with the pig and the color orange.</p><br>
      </div>
         <span>This article was last edited: Thursday, 27. January 2022.</span>
 </details>
```

```
.image-text{
display:flex;
}
```